# Cannot use useState in nextJs Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I am trying to make a filter to my movie list, my idea is to save all my movie in 'default', and filtering 'default' when I need, but I get an error like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
 const [datas, setData] = useState<string[]>([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [default, setDefault] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
      setLoading(true)
      await fetch("https://seleksi-sea-2023.vercel.app/api/movies")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData(data)
        setDefault(data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      
    };

    fetchData()
  }, []);

  const getCategory = async(t: string) => {
    console.log(t)
    if(t == 'Kids'){
        const filteredMovie = default.filter(data => data.age_rating <= 12)
        setData(filteredMovie)
    }
    else if(t == 'Adults'){
        const filteredMovie = default.filter(data => data.age_rating > 12)
        setData(filteredMovie)
    }
  }
```

I can filtering my movie, and if you have a better idea, I am open; give me some advice.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is not with `useState`. `default` is a reserved word in javascript. change it to something else.

[from here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers#:%7E:text=Reserved%20words&text=Keywords%20are%20tokens%20that%20have,void%20%2C%20while%20%2C%20and%20with%20.)

> Keywords are tokens that have special meaning in JavaScript: break,
> case, catch, continue, debugger, default, delete, do, else, finally,
> for, function, if, in, instanceof, new, return, switch, this, throw,
> try, typeof, var, void, while, and with.